# How can I use "as" to say that something means two nouns instead of same degree of an adjective?

Tags: sentence-construction, as

I'd like to say:

> "love is as need as an investment that makes sense"

is this correct way? I want to use the shortest and most clear way to say that love is both need and an investment that makes sense. I can use both but then "that makes sense" refers to the both need and investment. I want it to refer to only the second part.

any advice?

Comment: I'd be inclined to say something like, **"Love is a necessity, and a worthwhile/rewarding investment"**. Although if we were to follow the wording you have stated, it could also be, **"Love is a need, and an investment that makes sense"**. Remember simple is sweet :)

Comment: Where are you getting this usage of "as"? Have you seen it used this way somewhere else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to say that love is both a need and an investment that makes sense, you'd say it like that. The "that makes sense" applies to the investment, not the need. If you're still uncertain that it is, you could say "love is both a need and a sensible investment."

In both of the aforementioned cases it seems more appropriate that the word *sensible* is used instead of *that makes sense* since both have the same meaning and the former is shorter and less wordy.